# Is мне stressed?

Tags: произношение, ударение

Is **мне** stressed (as in, is it pronounced **mnyeh**?)? Is this always the case? If not, what are some examples? Also, what about other short words such as **по**?

Comment: I probably did not get your question, but at least one syllable has to be stessed in any case. In this word there is only one syllable, so it has to be stressed.

Comment: @user996142 I was talking about in different phrases and circumstances, such as мне нравится and other phrases.

Comment: @Casey can you clarify what you mean? It is one-syllable word after all indeed.

Comment: @user996142 *бы* and *у* only have one syllable; is there stress anywhere in them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pronoun **мне** will be always pronounced as **mnyeh**, no matter if its stressed or not. There's no way you'd say **mni**.

If you say it in a flowing speech (say, for example, "мне нравится этот фильм") you have basically several options of stressing to report fine meaning of what you're trying to say. Normally if you just report the fact that you liked the film you pronounce "мне нравится" joined together putting primary stress on "нравится", so you have something like (mnyeh-NRUH-vih-tsuh). If you stress the word "мне" putting secondary stress on the verb you would mean that you personally liked it as opposed to someone else who didn't. The same applies to the rest of the words in this example.

**По** is a preposition and it is also unstressed most of the times and you should pronounce it as any syllable "-по-" in its unstressed position (**-puh-**).

Now thinking about the syllable -мне- in unstressed position, I'd say that I would always pronounce it like -mnyeh- (consider the following examples: **мнемóника**, **камнепáд** or **сомневáющийся**) but maybe there's a counter-example I can't think of.

UPD 2016-03-02: Transcriptions edited according to hints of @YellowSky

UPD UPD 2016-03-02: As pointed out by @DenisKreshikhin standard pronunciation of a **-e-** following a soft consonant in an unstressed syllable followed by the stressed one would lean towards **-и-** rather than **-e-**

Comment: Very thorough answer. Thank you very much for your answer and the examples of stress in the phrases!

Comment: I think your examples of unstressed -мне- are expected to be read closer to [мни], for example сомневаться has the [following transcription](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F): [ səmnʲɪˈvatʲsə ]. [This service](http://easypronunciation.com/ru/russian-phonetic-transcription-converter) gives th following transcription of your examples: mnʲɪmˈonʲɪkə, kəmnʲɪpˈat, səmnʲɪvˈajʉɕːɪjsʲə.

Comment: @Artemix  I had my doubts too but double checked myself on the recording. I slightly reduce "e" towards "i" but it's a clear "e". But **it might as well be regional thing** since I grew up in Kazakhstan and from my experience Russian pronunciation in Kazakhstan tends to be Siberian-like (excluding, of course, people strongly influenced by their native Kazakh language).

Comment: The particle _ся_ is always pronounced as [sə], never as [sʲə], and the Russian _a_ in practical transcription is rendered as "uh", that's why mnyeh-NRUH-vih-tsuh, not mnyeh-NRAH-vih-tsyah, and -puh-, not -pah-.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my post. Can you please provide a source for this kind of transcription guidelines?

Comment: @YellowSky Вы путаете, так произносится не окончание ся, а сочетание "тся" произносится как [tsə] только в глаголах в неопределенной форме третьего лица. Во всех остальных случаях правильно произносить [sʲə]. http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/73.htm

Comment: @DmitriyPurgin Про произношение безударных тоже можете почитать у Розенталя. После мягких согласных в безударном положении должен быть звук близкий к [и] - мн[и]моника, камн[и]пад и т.д. http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/73.htm

Comment: @DenisKreshikhin Розенталь, безусловно, авторитет, но, как я писал выше, возможно это региональное различие.

Comment: @DmitriyPurgin Да, безусловно, в Рязани можно услышать и мн[я]мон[я]ка, и камн[я]пад. Но нормированное произношение описано у Розенталя.

Comment: @DenisKreshikhin Так я же не спорю, к тому же в оригинальном посте я указал, что это лично я бы произнёс так. Язык ведь не на бумаге, а в головах у людей. Кстати, вполне возможно, что на самом деле мы говорим об одном и том же звуке, который мы интерпретируем по-разному.

Comment: Вот интересный пример по поводу интерпретации звуков из моего опыта. Австрийцы практически не слышат разницы в произношении [б] и [п] без аспирации, они слышат оба звука как [б]. Если только добавить аспирацию к [п], они тут же слышат его глухим.